# Why do different atomic isotopes have different atomic spectrums?

Tags: mass, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, isotopes

We know that different elements have different atomic spectrums as a result of the difference in charge and electron shielding that occurs when extra protons are added to a nucleus.

We also know that deuterium was discovered in 1931 by Harold Urey as a result of the different atomic spectra between hydrogen-1 and hydrogen-2. As there is no change in charge within the nucleus, why does the atomic spectrum change?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When we solve the Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom, we find that the energy levels are

$$
E_n = -\frac{\alpha^2 m c^2}{2 n^2} = -\frac{\rm 13.6\,eV}{n^2}
$$

where $\alpha \approx 1/137$ is the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) and $c$ is the speed of light.  We usually approximate $m$ as the electron mass, but that's actually wrong. The correct mass parameter is the "reduced mass" $\mu$ of the electron-nucleus system, which obeys

$$
\frac 1\mu = \frac1{m_\text{e}} + \frac1{m_\text{n}}
= \frac 1{m_\text{e}} \left(
1 + \frac{m_\text{e}}{m_\text{n}}
\right)
$$

The extra neutron in deuterium roughly doubles the nuclear mass, which changes $\mu$ (and therefore $E$) starting in its fourth or fifth significant figure.

Comment: Does this mean that the relative change between the spectra of hydrogen-3 and hydrogen-2 is less than that of hydrogen-2 and hydrogen-1 because going from hydrogen-1 to hydrogen-2 roughly doubles the mass but going from hydrogen-2 to hydrogen-3 only increases the mass by ≈ 1.5x?

Comment: That's right — though in a real spectrometer you'd mostly be comparing tritium to protium.

Comment: There is also a contribution from the (small) change in the nuclear charge distribution. In hydrogen it is tiny compared to the mass effect, but at large Z this is the dominant effect.

Comment: @CWPP Can you give a reference for such very large hyperfine effects?

Comment: @my2cts [Bill King's textbook](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780306415623).

Comment: Nuclear spin! Also, some extreme examples of reduced mass in [this answer to *What is a "hydrogen-like" or "hydrogenic" atom?*](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/80320/16035)

Comment: How does the effect of the mass difference compare to that of the spin-spin interaction?

Comment: @Sandejo That’s a big topic, and hyperfine spectroscopy isn’t my area. I suggest you ask a new question.